# How to display .mkv files on html from Absolute path without user input

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to display a video on my website by using an absolute path as the source of the video but when i try to run the website, the video is not displayed.

main.py

```
@app.route("/view" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view():
    if request.method == "POST" and 'name' in request.form:
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        name = request.form['name']
        script = request.form['script']
        file = request.form['file']
        movie = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\ehds2\\Downloads', file)
        print(movie)
        return render_template('view.html', cursor=cursor, name=name, script=script, movie=movie)
    else:
        return render_template('view.html')
```

view.html

```
{% block content %}

    <div id="list">
       <p>{{ script }}</p>

         <video width="500px" height="500px" controls="controls">
             <source src="file:///{{ movie }}" type="video/mkv" />
         </video>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is what I have tried and it still did not work out.
Could someone please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That can't possibly work if the browser is not on the same computer as the server.  The browser can only see local files, not remote files.